# How to use multiple cache sink in a single data flow and use outputs of both the sinks in a pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am having two cache sinks in a dataflow, when selecting write to activity output for both the sinks throws validation error: Multiple Cache sinks found with output set to 'true'. Output for only one sink is supported.
Is there any workaround / Solution to use output of both the sinks in a single pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only 1 cached sink can send output from a data flow. Would it be possible to combine or union multiple data streams into a single cache sink in your data flow?

Comment: Hi @Mark yes i had to do that because multiple sink was not possible. Thanks